# git set remote head so I can delete a branch

Tags: git

Trying to set a remote HEAD in git.  Should be:

```
git remote set-head origin develop
```

That's supposed to set the head to the develop branch in the origin.  Doesn't seem to work.

I'm trying to delete the remote branch `Project/Setup`, but getting the error:

> refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/Project/Setup To myurl ! [remote rejected] Project/Setup (deletion of the current branch prohibited)

Not sure why the `set-head` isn't working. No error, no response in the console at all, just doesn't appear to do anything.  The local repo's head is in the develop branch, where it should be.

If it matters, my origin remote has two push urls, wouldn't think it'd make a difference (neither updates properly).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `git remote set-head` command only works in your local repository.  (As such, it's almost a form of false advertising: it sure *seems like* `git remote set-head` should send a request to the remote to set *its* `HEAD`.)  In this case, since you're following this up with a request sent to the remote to *delete* a branch, which really does require that the remote have set its `HEAD`, `git remote set-head` is useless.

Git has no built-in method of asking another Git repository to change its `HEAD` (or, for that matter, any other symbolic reference).  So you need to use some other method, such as a web interface that lets you do it, or to log in on the remote machine (in the case of corporate servers where you have direct access).

Comment: "it sure _seems like_" - indeed, it sure does!  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out (sort of, feels like a workaround, but...)

Went to github and bitbucket and noticed the `Project/Setup` branch was set as the primary/main branch.  Reset those to master, than the remote delete worked fine.